# Are counters idempotent since Cassandra 2.1?

Tags: cassandra

This document seems to imply so:

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-1-a-better-implementation-of-counters

*"The crucial difference is that rather than logging counter deltas (increments) directly to the commit log – making replay non-idempotent and potentially unsafe – Cassandra will now read the current value for every counter update and apply the delta"*

Does that mean that if a counter update times out, retry could be done without fear of over-counting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it does not.

It means that if a node crashes the commitlog replay is idempotent.

The counter update timeout is another story and there is a risk of over-counting. I think counters are useful only if you do not care about imprecision. Otherwise you should use lightweight transaction, which has a cost in terms of performance.